# Inventory Source Out Of Stock

Tags: magento2

i am update my stock below is my code

```
$product=$this->_product->getById($productId); //load product which you want to update stock
    $sku=$product->getSku();

    $sources = $this->getSourceItemsBySku->execute($sku);

        $quantity = 0;
        foreach ($sources as $index => $source) {

            if($source->getSourceCode()== $inventory_source) { //@todo load source data i.e sync with QBO

                $quantity = $receive_qty + $source->getQuantity();
                $sourceItem = $this->_sourceItemFactory->create();
                $sourceItem->setSourceCode($inventory_source);
                $sourceItem->setSku($sku);
                $sourceItem->setQuantity($quantity);
                $sourceItem->setStatus(1);
                $this->_sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
            }
        }
```

this issue is how i update stock status from out of stock to in stock by this code?

Comment: Try this $sourceItem->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $quantity , 'is_in_stock' => 1]);

Comment: You need to set `is_in_stock` property. Check https://webkul.com/blog/update-product-stock-programmatically-in-magento2/